# Looping Through Dates in strSQL in Access VBA

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I have this code in Access:

```
Sub SampleReadCurve()

Dim rs As Recordset
Dim iRow As Long, iField As Long
Dim strSQL As String
Dim CurveID As Long
Dim MarkRunID As Long
Dim MaxOfMarkAsofDate As Date



CurveID = 15

MaxOfMarkAsofDate = #7/22/2015#


strSQL = "SELECT * FROM VolatilityOutput WHERE CurveID=" & CurveID & " AND MaxOfMarkAsofDate=#" & MaxOfMarkAsofDate & "# ORDER BY MaxOfMarkasOfDate, MaturityDate"


Debug.Print strSQL

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, Type:=dbOpenDynaset, Options:=dbSeeChanges)

If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    Debug.Print vbCrLf
    Debug.Print "First", rs.Fields("ZeroCurveID"), rs.Fields("MaturityDate"), rs.Fields("ZeroRate"), rs.Fields("DiscountFactor")
    rs.MoveLast
    Debug.Print "Last", rs.Fields("ZeroCurveID"), rs.Fields("MaturityDate"), rs.Fields("ZeroRate"), rs.Fields("DiscountFactor")
    Debug.Print "There are " & rs.RecordCount & " records and " & rs.Fields.Count & " fields."

    Dim BucketTermAmt As Long
    Dim BucketTermUnit As String
    Dim BucketDate As Date
    Dim MarkAsOfDate As Date
    Dim InterpRate As Double
    Dim I As Integer

    BucketTermAmt = 3
    BucketTermUnit = "m"
    BucketDate = DateAdd(BucketTermUnit, BucketTermAmt, MaxOfMarkAsofDate)
    InterpRate = CurveInterpolateRecordset(rs, BucketDate)
    Debug.Print BucketDate, InterpRate




End If
End Sub
```

The table VolatilityOutput has a list of dates with an associated value. This code interpolates a value for a given MaxofMarkAsofDate using the closest values found in the table.

Right now, I have MaxofMarkAsofDate selected from the table as part of an strSQL statement. The code returns the correct value for #7/22/2015#.

However, I need to get the values for the 76 dates prior to #7/22/2015#. I can accomplish this by manually entering #7/21/2015#, #7/20/2015# etc for each date. I would like to do this a faster way if possible. I want to use a loop however I don't know how to combine loops with strSQL statements in Access.

Comment: Why can't you use AND MaxOfMarkAsofDate=<#" & MaxOfMarkAsofDate?

Comment: I am not sure - I tried replacing my code with that and it gave me a syntax error. what is this meant to do?

Comment: Instead of just taking the value it equals, it would take all values equal to or less than it.  Not sure if that gets you where you need to be or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CurveID = 15

Dim i As Integer    
For i = 0 to 76
    MaxOfMarkAsofDate = #7/22/2015# - i

    'Your inner code here '
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I get a Next Without For error here. Can I subtract an integer from a date?

Comment: Yes, VBA performs the implicit conversion.  I'll add the before and after lines of your existing code for context.

Comment: Ah I understand now thank you. That works perfectly.

Comment: If you don't mind, could I ask you a follow up question? I get a range of numbers as output from running this subroutine, i.e 76 InterpRates. How can I store this output as an array afterwards? I am planning to write a function that takes the 76 InterpRates as an input.

Comment: @varunchandra: Better to ask that as a separate question.  Feel free to link to the new question from these comments.

Comment: Please see <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34613860/storing-arrays-in-access-vba>