# Data Conversion Type Error in VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, ms-access

I am trying to access elements of a table in Access VBA as part of a function. However, I am getting an error message "Data Type Conversion Error". I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here.

The following subroutine populates the elements of the table that I am trying to access, "HolderTable".

```
Sub SampleReadCurve()

Dim rs As Recordset
Dim rs2 As Recordset
Dim iRow As Long, iField As Long
Dim strSQL As String
Dim CurveID As Long
Dim MarkRunID As Long
Dim MaxOfMarkAsofDate As Date
Dim userdate As String

DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM HolderTable"
'Clears out the old array from the holder table.

CurveID = 15

Dim I As Integer
Dim x As Date

userdate = InputBox("Please Enter the Date (mm/dd/yyyy)")

x = userdate

For I = 0 To 150

MaxOfMarkAsofDate = x - I


strSQL = "SELECT * FROM VolatilityOutput WHERE CurveID=" & CurveID & " AND MaxOfMarkAsofDate=#" & MaxOfMarkAsofDate & "# ORDER BY MaxOfMarkasOfDate, MaturityDate"

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, Type:=dbOpenDynaset, Options:=dbSeeChanges)
Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("HolderTable")

If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then

    rs.MoveFirst

    rs.MoveLast

    Dim BucketTermAmt As Long
    Dim BucketTermUnit As String
    Dim BucketDate As Date
    Dim MarkAsOfDate As Date
    Dim InterpRate As Double

    BucketTermAmt = 3
    BucketTermUnit = "m"
    BucketDate = DateAdd(BucketTermUnit, BucketTermAmt, MaxOfMarkAsofDate)
    InterpRate = CurveInterpolateRecordset(rs, BucketDate)
    Debug.Print BucketDate, InterpRate
    rs2.AddNew
    rs2("BucketDate") = BucketDate
    rs2("InterpRate") = InterpRate
    rs2.Update

End If

Next I

Dim vol As Long

vol = EWMA(0.94)

Debug.Print vol


End Sub
```

This is the function, EWMA, which is giving me the error message. Basically it is just setting up a series of simple operations on the elements of HolderTable, which is populated by values derived in the SampleReadCurve subroutine.

```
Function EWMA(Lambda As Double) As Double

    Dim Price1 As Double, Price2 As Double
    Dim vInterpRate() As Variant
    Dim SumWtdRtn As Double
    Dim I As Long
    Dim m As Double
    Dim rec As Recordset
    Dim BucketTermAmt As Long

    BucketTermAmt = 3

    Dim LogRtn As Double, RtnSQ As Double, WT As Double, WtdRtn As Double

m = BucketTermAmt

Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT InterpRate FROM HolderTable")

Do While rec.EOF = False

rec("InterpRate") = vInterpRate

    Price1 = Exp(vInterpRate(I - 1, 1) * (m / 12))

    Price2 = Exp(vInterpRate(I, 1) * (m / 12))

    LogRtn = Log(Price1 / Price2)

    RtnSQ = LogRtn ^ 2

    WT = (1 - Lambda) * Lambda ^ (I - 2)

    WtdRtn = WT * RtnSQ

    SumWtdRtn = SumWtdRtn + WtdRtn

Loop

EWMA = SumWtdRtn ^ (1 / 2)

End Function
```

HolderTable has two fields, BucketDate and InterpRate, both of which have the Data Type "Short Text". I get the Data Type Conversion Error message at the line

```
   Price1 = Exp(vInterpRate(I - 1, 1) * (m / 12))
```

Changing the Data Type still results in the same error message when run. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Now that I see this, I'm not so sure vInterpRate(I - 1, 1) makes sense.  If vInterpRate were a **function**, it would.  But vInterpRate is a **variable**.  If you substitute the number 5 for vInterpRate, it makes no sense.  5(I - 1, 1).  You need to figure out what you're trying to do there, and make adjustments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original:
Are you sure it's not supposed to be:

```
vInterpRate = rec("InterpRate")
```

instead of

```
rec("InterpRate") = vInterpRate()
```

Revised:

```
dim x as integer
Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT InterpRate FROM HolderTable")
x = 0
Do While rec.EOF = False
redim(vInterpRate, x+1) 'need to preserve don't remember if this is default in vba
  vInterpRate(x) = rec("InterpRate")
  x = x + 1
  rec.next
Loop

for i = 1 to x do

  Price1 = Exp(vInterpRate(I - 1, 1) * (m / 12))

  Price2 = Exp(vInterpRate(I, 1) * (m / 12))

  LogRtn = Log(Price1 / Price2)

  RtnSQ = LogRtn ^ 2

  WT = (1 - Lambda) * Lambda ^ (I - 2)

  WtdRtn = WT * RtnSQ

  SumWtdRtn = SumWtdRtn + WtdRtn
next i
```

There are probably bugs in the code as I don't have a vba compiler and it's been a long time since I've worked in it, but I think this should point you in the right direction if I'm interpreting what you're looking for correctly.

Comment: You're right, it should be without the brackets. I still get the same error message though.

Comment: Without the parenthesis, and also it was backwards.  

Also try wrapping the variant (which at this point is a string) with CInt: 
Price1 = Exp(cint(vInterpRate(I - 1, 1)) * (m / 12))

Comment: Sorry, the more I look at the code, the more I'm confused - what do you expect this line `rec("InterpRate") = vInterpRate` to do exactly?

Comment: Oh I see, thank you. However it gives me a Type mismatch error now at the line vInterpRate = rec("InterpRate"), which doesn't make any sense to me, is it wrong to have it as Variant?

Comment: In the table HolderTable, I have a field called InterpRate. I am trying to access the elements of that field in that line.

Comment: it's more of a problem that rec("InterpRate") is not an array.  It's a single value of one row of the recordset.  I'll update my answer to show what I think you're trying to do.

Comment: thank you that's very helpful, I see what was wrong before. could you explain to me what you are trying to do in this line? ReDim(vInterpRate, x+1). Would it be correct to rewrite it as 
ReDim Preserve vInterpRate(x + 1)

Comment: That was my fault, varun.  I didn't realize at first that you absolutely had to use an array for this.  Brian's answer should fix my mistake.  I apologize.

Comment: no problem at all, I am very close to getting it working now from your answer and Brian's, I see what I was doing wrong before,

Comment: Yes, that would be the correct way of writing that: ReDim Preserve vInterpRate(x + 1)

Comment: should it be "Loop" or "Next I" at the end after SumWtdRtn? If I keep Loop, I get a Loop Without Do error. However "Next I" gives me a Subscript out of Range error for the array.

Comment: Next I - sorry about that, like I said, haven't worked in it in a while

Comment: thanks. any idea why it might give me a Subscript out of Range error at the line Price1 = Exp(vInterpRate(I - 1, 1) * (m / 12))?

Comment: `vInterpRate` appears to be referenced as a 2 dimensional array., referenced as `vInterpRate(x, y)`  I don't know how or if you use this later for some other reason, but my guess would be get rid of the second dimensional reference?